# gcov froze when giving -a option?

Tags: gcov, lcov

When I do gcov . there is no problems. However, when I do gcov -a . gcov froze. The last few lines of the output is:

File '/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp'
Lines executed:78.18% of 55
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:creating 'iserializer.hpp.gcov'

File '/usr/include/boost/serialization/extended_type_info_typeid.hpp'
Lines executed:40.74% of 27
/usr/include/boost/serialization/extended_type_info_typeid.hpp:creating 'extended_type_info_typeid.hpp.gcov

Do you know why that is happening ? The reason I need "-a" is when I use lcov, it gives that option to gcov, I can hack geninfo to ignore that option but I prefer not to since I'll eventually run lcov on a public system.

Thank you for any inputs!

Answer (score 0):

I also have code that uses boost::serialization - the lcov process isn't /frozen/, it just takes a very very long time to run. I have had it complete successfully after several hours, and I finally do get a nice lcov report.

It would be lovely to be able to exclude processing of the boost serialization code when running lcov -c but I have not been able to figure out exactly how to do that yet. (Of course, I /want/ to get coverage over the code that uses boost serialization, but not the boost headers themselves) Even putting // LCOV_EXCL_START & LCOV_EXCL_STOP around the majority of the serialization code doesn't work, as I think those exclusion markers are only used when genhtml is called, not on lcov -c.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I only ran it for like an hr, saw it still consuming CPU cycles, thought it went into infinite loop and stopped it. I'll try to let it run next time. Thanks!